# Data is being deleted from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, computer-forensics

I've got a really horrible problem on my hands, for some reason data is being wiped from a particular table's column and I have no idea why.

The table is called `events`.  Inside the table there are a number of columns, name, date etc however recently I put a field in called 'schedule' this is of type TEXT.

On the web page, you can edit the event in different tabs and create a schedule (fields using jQuery clone / etc) and then when the schedule data gets saved into th database the HTML $_POST data gets converted into a JSON array using `json_encode`:

```
$db->prepared['schedule'] = json_encode(
    array(
        "scheduleday" => ($_POST['scheduleday'] ?? array()), 
        "scheduletime" => ($_POST['scheduletime'] ?? array()), 
        "scheduledescription" => ($_POST['scheduledescription'] ?? array()), 
        "schedulevenue" => ($_POST['schedulevenue'] ?? "")
    )
);
```

The resulting json array could look like this, for example:

```
{"scheduleday":{"1":"2020-08-25","2":"2020-08-26"},"scheduletime":{"1":["19:30","20:00 - 20:50"],"2":["14:00 - 14:50","14:50 - 15:00","15:00 - 15:50","15:50 - 16:00","16:00 - 16:50"]},"scheduledescription":{"1":["Introduction","John Smith"],"2":["John Smith","Break","John Smith teaching","Break","John Smith teaching"]},"schedulevenue":"1 Acia Avenue"}
```

Straight after this is INSERTED or UPDATEd into the mysql database it is then sent to a function that uses fpdf to turn the json array into a PDF which can be downloaded.

This works well, apart from one problem.  Random (or what appears to be random) schedules are going missing.  We can create a schedule one day and then a week later, or a few days later, suddenly the file will have been deleted and the column in the table removed.  No other data in the table is getting deleted, nothing apart from the schedule.

Here's what I've tried to find out whats going on:

**SQL Trigger**

I've set a trigger on the event table which dumps data into a table called `event_trigger` AFTER an update is run.  This is the code for the trigger:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `event_trigger` (oldID,name,old_schedule,new_schedule) VALUES
(OLD.id,
 OLD.name,
 OLD.schedule,
 NEW.schedule);
END
```

This has been helpful in the sense that I now know if there is an event with a schedule missing, because the NEW.schedule will be empty.  However that last two times a schedule has gone missng (yesterday and today, in fact) its been outside of office hours, 18:45 and 19:22 so no one should be performing any updates on events in those times.

**.txt File Log**

The other thing i've done is on the page where the events are updated I've put a text log, which dumps the prepared variables, the SQL statement and the user and the user ID to a text file.  Unfortunately this isnt working because when a schedule goes missing, its not getting logged in there.  All that tells me is that its happening somewhere else.

I dont know how to narrow this down further.  There is no user activity at the times when an event is deleted.  The closest i've gotten is using the TRIGGER.  But I am so limited as the information from the trigger is not enough; I can't get IP, SQL statement, user ID or anything like that.  Just the OLD and NEW variables.

Can anyone help me think of ways to investigate, I'd be so grateful.  This has been going on for over a month now, and its infuriating because I just cannot see why it is happening.

The only extra option I can think of doing is turning on full SQL logs, but I am reluctant to do that as it will slow the server down immensly.

Comment: are there any other pages / features in your application which allow such a deletion to happen (legitimately)?

Comment: If  you have access to the code then you can do quite a bit, including using ORM library derivative (your own) to hook into deletion methods. Otherwise you can set up database logging or xhprof profiling to determine the details of where deletion is invoked or what the query looks like.

Comment: I think there is some maintenance script that recreate the table. The strangest behaviour, IMHO, is that "the column in the table removed". This can only happen if some task is recreating the table with an old schema. Investigate the maintenance tasks and search for "CREATE TABLE" or "DROP TABLE"

Comment: @NicolaLepetit sorry that was bad phrasing, I meant to say  the data in the column is removed, not the column itself!

Answer (score 1):

Have you examined your web server's logs? If this data corruption comes in via your web application, you should be able to see the exact time and originating IP address of the unfortunate event. You may also be able to figure out which page of your web app caused the problem.

To track things down more accurately in your database server, add, to your `event_trigger` table, these columns:

- timestamp  (when the trigger fired)
- user  (the MySQL host and user that issued the UPDATE that fired the trigger)
- query (the text of the UPDATE query)

Then change your trigger to say

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO event_trigger 
        (oldID,name,old_schedule,new_schedule, ts, user, query)
  VALUES
  (OLD.id,
   OLD.name,
   OLD.schedule,
   NEW.schedule,
   NOW(),
   CURRENT_USER(),
   (SELECT INFO FROM information_schema.process_list WHERE id=CONNECTION_ID())
);
END
```

Then, your event_trigger table will show you the user `webapp@localhost` or `cybercreep@cracker.example.com` that issued the UPDATE, when it was issued, and what the exact query was.

(With the exact query you can search your code base to try to track down what function is running amok.)

Once you know what database user is issuing the query, you can consider suspending access for that particular user after business hours, and see who complains. But keep in mind that the database user is probably the generic username used by your web application, so it may not tell you much.

It's very likely that this is a legitimate web app user misusing, by mistake, your system.

**Pro tip** : Put [automatic timestamp columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) in all your application tables so you can keep track of changes. Add

```
 ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

columns to your tables, and MySQL takes care of updating them.

**Pro tip 2** (harder) add an action log table to your database, and make your web app insert a row to it each time a user takes an action. Then you can run queries like "who did what yesterday between 19:00 and 19:30?" Customer support people love to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! A couple of things: The `SELECT info` query you suggested just returns the Trigger SQL, and not the last SQL which Is what I need, so that does help.  I had tried that before.  Also I do keep logs of user activity, and there are no users doing anything when the event happens.  I've also got the timestamp columns.  Have you got any idea why the `SELECT info` query is returning the trigger SQL only?